# C++ operator overloading show strange behaviour

Tags: c++

i write one simple program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Interval
{
public:
    Interval(int m_input, int s_input)
    {
        minutes =  m_input + s_input / 60;
        seconds = s_input % 60;
    }   

    void Print()            const
    {
        cout << minutes << " : " << seconds << endl;
    }

    int GetSeconds()        const
    {
        return 60 * minutes + seconds;
    }

    Interval& operator+(const Interval& rhs)
    {
        minutes = this->minutes + rhs.minutes;
        seconds = this->seconds + rhs.seconds;
        return Interval(minutes, seconds);
    }

    Interval& operator-(const Interval& rhs)
    {
         int totalSeconds = this->GetSeconds() - rhs.GetSeconds();
         return Interval(0, totalSeconds);
    }

private:
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

int main()
{
    Interval t1(7, 45);
    t1.Print();
    Interval t2(3, 75);
    t2.Print();
    Interval t3 = t1 + t2;
    t3.Print();
    Interval t4 = t3 - t1;
    t4.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

It's Output is
7 : 45
4 : 15
12 : 0
0 : 0  <-----------Please Notice this one.

but when make some changes in our program like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Interval
{
public:
    Interval(int m_input, int s_input)
    {
        minutes =  m_input + s_input / 60;
        seconds = s_input % 60;
    }   

    void Print()            const
    {
        cout << minutes << " : " << seconds << endl;
    }

    int GetSeconds()        const
    {
        return 60 * minutes + seconds;
    }

    Interval& operator-(const Interval& rhs)
    {
         int totalSeconds = this->GetSeconds() - rhs.GetSeconds();
         return Interval(0, totalSeconds);
    }

private:
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    friend Interval& operator+(const Interval& lhs, const Interval& rhs);
};

Interval& operator+(const Interval& lhs, const Interval& rhs)
{
    int minutes = lhs.minutes + rhs.minutes;
    int seconds = lhs.seconds + rhs.seconds;
    return Interval(minutes, seconds);
}

int main()
{
    Interval t1(7, 45);
    t1.Print();
    Interval t2(3, 75);
    t2.Print();
    Interval t3 = t1 + t2;
    t3.Print();
    Interval t4 = t3 - t1;
    t4.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

it shows output
7 : 45
4 : 15
12 : 0
4 : 15  ---> look it this why i don't know :( please enplane.

thanks for your help

Vishal

Comment: Are you going to make me mentally `diff` these two programs? Can't you narrow down the problem any further?

Answer (score 4):

Your first version modifies member variables, when it shouldn't:

```
Interval& operator+(const Interval& rhs)
{
    minutes = this->minutes + rhs.minutes;
    seconds = this->seconds + rhs.seconds;
    return Interval(minutes, seconds);
}
```

The subsequent subtraction operation is performed on the modified `Interval`.

Your second version does not make this modification to member variables:

```
Interval& operator+(const Interval& lhs, const Interval& rhs)
{
    int minutes = lhs.minutes + rhs.minutes;
    int seconds = lhs.seconds + rhs.seconds;
    return Interval(minutes, seconds);
}
```

Also, in both cases you are returning a reference to a local variable, which is wrong.

Comment: hi i am poor in explanation

Answer (score 1):

These operators

```
Interval& operator+(const Interval& rhs)
{
    minutes = this->minutes + rhs.minutes;
    seconds = this->seconds + rhs.seconds;
    return Interval(minutes, seconds);
}


Interval& operator-(const Interval& rhs)
{
     int totalSeconds = this->GetSeconds() - rhs.GetSeconds();
     return Interval(0, totalSeconds);
}
```

are invalid. They return references to local objects that will be destroyed after operators will finish their works.

Also in the first operator you change data members of the first operand

```
    minutes = this->minutes + rhs.minutes;
    seconds = this->seconds + rhs.seconds;
```

because in these statements minutes and seconds are equivalent to this->minutes and this->seconds

Change them the following way

```
Interval  operator +(const Interval& rhs) const
{
    int minutes = this->minutes + rhs.minutes;
    int seconds = this->seconds + rhs.seconds;
    return Interval( minutes, seconds);
}

Interval operator -(const Interval& rhs) const
{
     int totalSeconds = this->GetSeconds() - rhs.GetSeconds();
     return Interval(0, totalSeconds);
}
```